# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when submitting credentials to https website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Yahoo Finance will be finally deprecated this year and I am in the process for an alternate reliable data provider. I am doing some web scraping to download historical stock data.

In a nutshell,

1. I have signed up for their service. =)
2. I am using fake_user agent and select one header at random to use at login.
3. I am trying to pass the credentials in the following line : **payload = {'redirect_url': base64.b64encode('https://website.com'), 'site': 'US', 'login_username': login_username, 'login_password': login_password}**
4. Retrieve the cookie.
5. Download the data and handle exceptions as required.

In theory it should work , but I am getting the following error : **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

I have tried converting str to byte as :

login_username = b'username'

or

login_username = username.encode('utf-8')

```
import base64
import time

import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

tickers = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB']

#Credentials to login
login_username = b'username'
login_password = b'password'


def get_magic_cookies():
    __urls__ = {'url_login': 'https://secure.website.com/login/secure'}

    payload = {'redirect_url': base64.b64encode('https://website.com'), 'site': 'MX', 'login_username': login_username,
           'login_password': login_password}
    headers = {UserAgent().random}

    _req = requests.post(__urls__['url_login'], data=payload, headers=headers)

    account_login = _req.history[0].headers['location']
    req_gsv = requests.get(account_login)  # Request for get SID values in content
    cookies_l = req_gsv.history[0].cookies

    if req_gsv.history:
        SID_USER = req_gsv.history[0].cookies['SID']
        USER_COOKIES = [_ for _ in req_gsv.history[0].cookies]
        USER_REQUEST = payload['login_username']

    return cookies_l

#get_magic_cookies()


def main():
    stocks_failed = []
    stocks_timeout = []

    for ticker in tickers:
        try:
            req  = requests.get('https://website.com/p.php?pid=data&daily=1&symbol={0}%5E{1}%2A'.format(ex, ticker)
            with open('path\\to\file\\{}.csv'.format(ticker), 'wb') as itd:
                itd.write(req.content)
                itd.close()


        except 'There were no results for your query' in req.content:
            print('[ {0} ] Stock Failed\n'.format(ticker))
            stocks_failed.append(ticker)

        except 'You have made too many requests. Please wait before trying to download again.' in req.content:
            print('{} Stock timeout'.format(ticker))
            stocks_timeout.append(ticker)
            time.sleep(80)  # Time of 80 secounds
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Couple of questions,

1. Why is it complaining even after I converted the str to bytes ?
2. What is the correct way to submit credentials to https website ?
3. Is there another way to submit credentials without having them hardcoded in the code making it more secure ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the first time I see `except` used this way, and I'm a little surprised it's not a syntax error. However I think you should use `if` instead of `except` for your checks. Also `.content` is bytes, use `.text` for strings.

Comment: The TypeError comes from `.b64encode()`; it expects bytes - `b64encode(b'url')`.